# Highcharts fails on load "evaluating Y[fa].pointer"

Tags: highcharts

I've noticed that users with desktop and mobile versions of Safari and Chrome are seeing quite a few errors when loading the Highcharts (3.0.10) script, like:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Y[fa].pointer')
```

But I haven't been able to reproduce this locally, so I'm wondering if anyone else has seen similar errors, or has ideas what could be causing these errors?

Comment: With previous version of Highcharts, problem also appears ?

Comment: Don't know about previous versions of Highcharts as I've only started logging in-browser errors recently. I haven't been able to reproduce the issue myself, otherwise the first thing I'd try would be reproduce the issue with the previous version of Highcharts as well.

Comment: ok so we're waiting for the demo.

Comment: I guess it's the same as [this bug](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2845).

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same error on mobile - but only on apple phones.  Does not repo on my HTC One.

PS I am seeing this issue on PhoneGap app I am building.

**UPDATE**: Error only happens on version 3.0.10.  I verified it is not reproducible on v3.0.8 and v3.0.9 for my scenario.

Comment: I guess it's the same as [this bug](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2845).